# Reset password no funciona

Tags: php, html, laravel

Acabo de empezar un nuevo proyecto de laravel, y el problema que tengo es que tras hacer el comando de `php artisan make:auth` se me genera el login, el registro y el formulario de recuperación de usuarios, todo perfecto.

Configuro el correo y efectivamente todo funciona correctamente, hasta que, tras ir al enlace que me manda al correo cuando intento recuperar la contraseña, se abre correctamente ya el formulario para resetear la contraseña y el primer error que me salía era: 
`" The password does not match"`
Y obviamente debería de funcionar sin mas, ya que es autogenerado por laravel, digo yo, pero realice algunos cambios en la vista, y ya no me arroja el error, ahora simplemente pasa de pagina y me arroja el siguiente error:

`TokenMismatchException in compiled.php line 3227:`

Aqui el codigo de la vista:

```
<body data-open="hover" data-menu="horizontal-menu" data-col="1-column" class="horizontal-layout horizontal-menu 1-column  blank-page blank-page">
    <!-- ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->
    <div class="app-content container center-layout mt-2">
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="content-header row">
        </div>
        <div class="content-body"><section class="flexbox-container">
    <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4 col-xs-10 offset-xs-1 box-shadow-2 p-0">
        <div class="card border-grey border-lighten-3 px-2 py-2 m-0">
            <div class="card-header no-border pb-0">
                <div class="card-title text-xs-center">
                    <img id="branding-logo" src="../../images/globalretail.png" alt="branding logo">
                </div>

                <h6 class="card-subtitle line-on-side text-muted text-xs-center font-small-3 pt-2">
                    <span>Introduce tu nueva contraseña</span>
                </h6>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body collapse in">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <form class="form-horizontal form-simple" action="{{ url('/password/reset') }}" method ="post" >
<!--                        {{csrf_field()}}-->
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{$token}}">
<!--                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">-->
                        <fieldset class="form-group position-relative has-icon-left">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg input-lg" name ="email" id="email" placeholder="Introduzca su email" value="{{old('email')}}">
                            <div class="form-control-position"><i class="icon-head"></i></div>
                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @endif
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="form-group position-relative has-icon-left">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg input-lg" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Contraseña nueva" required confirmed>
                            <div class="form-control-position"><i class="icon-key3"></i></div>
                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @endif
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="form-group position-relative has-icon-left">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg input-lg" name="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation" placeholder="Repita contraseña" >
                        <div class="form-control-position"><i class="icon-key3"></i></div>
                            @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                            <span class="help-block">
                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
                            </span>
                            @endif
                        </fieldset>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><i class="icon-unlock2"></i> Restablecer contraseña</button>
                        @include('errors.flash-message')
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

¿Tengo que realizar alguna configuración?

EDITO

Ruta del email:

> The requested URL
>   /password/reset/4625b4fb523847321308e02fba91ea5bddfa7ca3f2a0d7db583b39117af0ae25
>   was not found on this server.

Rutas:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function () {

Route::get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('login', ['as' =>'login', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin']);

//Route::get('password-request', 'Auth\PasswordController@getPasswordView');

Route::get('password/email','Auth\PasswordController@getEmail');
Route::post('password/emails','Auth\PasswordController@postEmail');

Route::get('password/reset/{token}','Auth\PasswordController@getReset');
Route::post('password/reset','Auth\PasswordController@postReset');
```

Realmente yo creo que está todo bien configurado y no se porque no me funciona el método de recuperación.

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Edito: Haciendo pruebas con los tokens y asi, he conseguido coger el token correcto para que me lo acepte, mi problema viene ahora con que laravel, no me coje la confirmacion de la contraseña y me arroja mi alerta de que no coinciden las contraseñas, he probado a modificar el metodo que se encarga de hacer las reglas pero aun asi, no consigo avanzar de ese punto.

```
protected function getResetValidationRules()
{
    return [
        'token' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|alpha_num|between:4,8',
    ];
}
```

Pero vamos que ni caso le hace.

Comment: Podrías agregar el enlace completo que te envía al correo, así como tu ruta por favor

Comment: Editado Levi, saludos.

Comment: Postea también el método del controlador si es que lo has modificado

Comment: No, la verdad no he realizado ninguna modificación, lo único que tengo en el controlador es lo que viene con el comando.